# ColdFusion - Google Maps API Key CFIDE reference in code?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In the ColdFusion Administrator interface, there is a place where you can store your Google Maps API Key.  The issue I'm having through is trying to figure out HOW to reference this key in code?  I don't see anything in the documentation.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used automatically in the `<cfmap>` tag.

```
<cfmap centeraddress="Los Angeles City Hall, 100 N Main St., Los Angeles, CA" />
```

Example from: http://www.isummation.com/blog/new-coldfusion-9-feature-cfmap/

Also see: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmap.html

Comment: thank you!  I've never used that tag (and don't thin I will) but it's good to know what it all ties together. Thank you!